# Populate dropdown list with prepared statements returning empty

Tags: php

Been scratching my head with this for hours and can't seem to return the results to the dropdown list using prepared statements.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT country_id, country_name, flag_file, 
header_img, intro FROM countries WHERE country_id = ? ORDER BY country_id");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $countryRow);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $countryName, $flag, $headerIMG, $intro);
$stmt->store_result();
$data = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    if(!$stmt) {
        echo "Failed to execute: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
    }

$data[] = array(
  "name" => $countryName,
  "flag" => $flag,
  "header" => $headerIMG,
  "intro" => $intro
);

$stmt->close();
}     
?>
```

And then the code for the dropdown list using a foreach loop:

```
<select type="text" name="país">
        <?php foreach ($data as $key => $value){ ?>
               <option value="<?=$value['country_id']?>"><?php echo 
               $value['country_name'] ?></option>
       <?php } ?>
</select>
```

First time using arrays. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are not using the array keys `country_id` and `country_name` when you put values into your array, but you are trying to access those when you output the data ... So the very first thing you please go do right now, is configure your PHP to properly inform you about such mistakes. Go research it if you don’t know how that is done.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `while` loop that you already have, instead of creating another `$data` array:

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT country_id, country_name, flag_file, 
header_img, intro FROM countries WHERE country_id = ? ORDER BY country_id");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $countryRow);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $countryName, $flag, $headerIMG, $intro);
$stmt->store_result();
$data = array();
$option = '';
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    if(!$stmt) {
        echo "Failed to execute: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
    }
    $option .= "<option value='" . $row['country_id']. "'>" . $row['country_name']. "</option>";
    /*$data[] = array(
        "name" => $countryName,
        "flag" => $flag,
        "header" => $headerIMG,
        "intro" => $intro
    );*/
    $stmt->close();
}     
?>
<select type="text" name="país">
    <?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Dear @Milan . Tks for your answer. I've tried your solution but it is still returning empty. I'm used to fetch results from the database using prepared statements and in this case, bind the results to different variables so that i can use them in other HTML elements but in the case of a dropdown list, somehow i can't work it out.

Comment: `print_r($row)` and check if you are getting correct `country_id` and `country_name`

Comment: Using print_r, it displays the integer 1.